# How to change time machine settings in Mac?

Tags: macos, time-machine

Say I want to exclude the desktop now from time machine. How would I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to System Preferences, Time Machine, then click on Options button.

Click on "+" and add the folders you want to exclude.

Comment: Once the Exclude list is open, you can also drag-and-drop a folder(s) from the finder.